# Cordova Android Permission Dialog Won't Prompt

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I am helping with some code for a AngularJS cordova application. I have a piece of code that on a button click triggers the record audio feature on Android.

While experimenting I wanted to let the "if" and "else" statements run the same bit of code (long story, but it's for testing purposes).

When I added that same code to the "else" statement, the button no longer triggers the record audio microphone permission. Instead, it logs the error message.

The only thing changed was adding the same code that once worked in the if statement to the else statement. I did not write the code so I am trying to understand it, I'm not sure what I am overlooking here.

For the sake of clarity, I am including both the original function and my updated function

**OriginalFunction**

```
//This pops the Android microphone recording

function recordButton(){
    if($rootScope.currentState === 'page1'){
        if (vm.recordReady){
            vm.recordReady = false;
            vm.recordRecording = true;
            dialogflowService.beginMicListener()
            .catch(err => {
                console.error('Audio Problem ', err);
                vm.recordReady = true;
                vm.recordRecording = false;
                vm.recordLoading = false;    
            });
        } else if (vm.recordRecording){
            vm.recordRecording = false;
            vm.recordLoading = endListener();
        }
    } else {
            console.log("Soemthing Else");
    }
}
```

**New Function**

```
function recordButton(){
    if($rootScope.currentState === 'page1'){
        if (vm.recordReady){
            vm.recordReady = false;
            vm.recordRecording = true;
            dialogflowService.beginMicListener()
            .catch(err => {
                console.error('Audio Problem ', err);
                vm.recordReady = true;
                vm.recordRecording = false;
                vm.recordLoading = false;    
            });
        } else if (vm.recordRecording){
            vm.recordRecording = false;
            vm.recordLoading = endListener();
        }
    } else {
        if (vm.recordReady){
            vm.recordReady = false;
            vm.recordRecording = true;
            dialogflowService.beginMicListener()
            .catch(err => {
                console.error('Audio Problem ', err); //This error prints and no Android microphone permission prompt shows
                vm.recordReady = true;
                vm.recordRecording = false;
                vm.recordLoading = false;    
            });
        } else if (vm.recordRecording){
            vm.recordRecording = false;
            vm.recordLoading = endListener();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is error you are getting in console logs?

Comment: I comment it out in the question, its 'Audio Problem' err and the err in this case prints "Missing Permission"